# How to keep the state of a component using Svelte?

Tags: state, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-material-ui, reactive-variable

I try to keep the state "open/close" of a "Panel" component. I use the [Accordion component from the library SMUI](https://sveltematerialui.com/demo/accordion/).

However, it keeps getting the default value when coming back to the page with the component.

I currently use reactive values as [suggested by SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/state-management#component-state-is-preserved). Where am I wrong?

```
<script lang="ts">
    let open: boolean = false;
    $: openPanel = open;
</script>

<Panel bind:open={openPanel}>
    <Header>
        <IconButton slot="icon" toggle pressed={openPanel}>
            <Icon class="material-icons" on>expand_less</Icon>
            <Icon class="material-icons">expand_more</Icon>
        </IconButton>
    </Header>
    ...
</Panel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State is not stored anywhere by default, so if you do not take care of that yourself, it will be gone.

I commonly use a [store](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store) to wrap [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) for less important/persistent state such as e.g. the open/closed state of this question.  SvelteKit also has a ["snapshots" feature](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/snapshots) which allows storing state for a history entry, though that will only restore the state on browser back navigation or reload.

For long lived configuration, e.g. the page theme, I would use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or store it in a DB on the server.

Comment: But the [documentation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/state-management#component-state-is-preserved) says "Component state is preservedpermalink". Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes, this is about SvelteKit not creating a new instance of a route when you navigate between different parameterized versions of the *same route*. Please read the full example to learn more.

Comment: My bad, indeed, my exact question is a few paragraph below in the documentation at *Storing ephemeral state in snapshotspermalink* . But anyway, now the role of the reactive value `$: variable = ''`is much clearer

Comment: @MikeCasanBallester: Note that snapshorts really are very limited and just exist for preserving state through history navigation.

Comment: indeed. It seems Snapshots does not "magically" work for nested components with open/close state. I will need to use a store I think.